# Spring Cache With Couchbase Using LoadTimeWeaving - Strangely Not Working

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-cache, load-time-weaving

I'm adding Spring Cache on an existing spring project using annotations. I'm using Couchbase as cache provider. I want to use load time weaving using AspectJ to allow private method calls and case class method calls to be cached as well.

It's been three days I'm stuck over this problem and I've read dozens of articles, documentations and examples but this thing just doesn't work.

This is what I've done -

```
@Configuration
@EnableSpringConfigured
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving = EnableLoadTimeWeaving.AspectJWeaving.ENABLED)
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableRetry
@PropertySource(
        value = {"classpath:application.properties", "classpath:${spring.profiles.active}.properties"},
        ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
public class BeanConfig implements LoadTimeWeavingConfigurer {

    ... various beans here ...

    @Override
    public LoadTimeWeaver getLoadTimeWeaver() {
        return new TomcatLoadTimeWeaver();// because I'm using Tomcat 7
    }

    @Bean
    public InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver loadTimeWeaver()  throws Throwable {
        return new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver();
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableSpringConfigured
@EnableCaching(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.foo.bar.dao.cache.couchbase")
public class CacheConfigurer extends CachingConfigurerSupport {
    @Bean
    @Override
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        ... cachemanager configuration here ...
    }
}
```

Then I have `@Chacheable` on a DAO method  on class, not on interface.

Finally, in my Tomcat 7's $CATALINA_HOME/conf/context.xml I have -

```
<Context>
    <Loader loaderClass="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader"/>    
</Context>
```

I have added following dependencies in pom.xml (its a maven project) -

- couchbase-spring-cache
- spring-aspects
- aspectjweaver
- aspectjrt
- spring-instrument
- spring-instrument-tomcat

If I do not use LTW caching works fine for methods calls arriving through interfaces (as it should). But after I enable LTW caching doesn't works at all - no caching for any method call, no errors either.

Has anyone tried using LTW for Spring cache with couchbase? What am I missing or doing wrong here?

I'm on Spring 4.3.5.Release.

**Update -**

Here is my bare-minimal code replicating the situation - https://github.com/harshilsharma63/spring-boilerplate-with-cache

Comment: nothing to do with couchbase really, the provider doesn't matter. You should be able to replicate this with in memory store. There is nothing obviously wrong that jumps at me. You can use `@Cacheable` on implementation without LTW by the way, just not private methods.

Comment: Can't you use a `-javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver.jar` as a JVM argument instead of the classloader magic needed if you don't?

Comment: Or even better, use compile-time weaving. Since you rely on AspectJ for transaction management already, which is not an optional feature of your application, you could simplify your app by bringing the weaving part out of your application run time into your build.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll I'll try using another cache provider just to verify.

Comment: @NándorElődFekete I already tried specifying custom classloader in tomcat context.xml as specified in question.
Compile time weaving is a possible solution to getting things running. I'll be exploring it.

Comment: You don't need the classloader magic if you're using a java agent for load-time weaving or you use compile-time weaving. Enabling a the LTW agent is as simple as specifying a command line argument for your JVM startup. Compile-time weaving is better though in all cases, except maybe if you want to weave dinamically loaded code, which is not available at compile time (e.g. plugins).

Comment: @StephaneNicoll I have uploaded minimal code which replicates this problem. Do you think you can take a look at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget classloader based load-time weaving, especially with Tomcat < 8.0. You'll have a lot of problems related to classloading order, with some classes being loaded before spring would install his weaving classloader, and you're gonna end-up with hard-to debug problems some of your classes not being weaved, etc. Instead, use a java agent.

Here's how to fix your config with Tomcat 7 by switching to java agent based weaving:

1. Remove `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving` annotations.
2. Remove `<Loader loaderClass...` from `context.xml`.
3. Add `-javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver.jar` to your JVM startup arguments.

If you're willing to move to Tomcat 8, here are the steps needed:

1. Move `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving=ENABLED)` to a separate configuration class, let's name it `WeavingConfig`.
2. Change your `WebInitializer` class so that for the `getRootConfigClasses()` you return only `WeavingConfig.class`.
3. Move other required config classes to `getServletConfigClasses()`.
4. Remove unneded configurations like `<Loader loaderClass...` from `context.xml`, `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`.
5. Profit.

Of course, the best would still be to just use compile time weaving.

Comment: " the best would still be to just use compile time weaving." - any particular reason why compile time weaving will still be best?

Comment: Also, any idea why Spring documentation differs vastly from what you suggested (which actually worked)?

Comment: With compile-time weaving, you move the performance penalty of weaving from load-time to build time, so startup time will be faster. It doesn't require you to modify runtime properties of the target system, like adding a java agent or modifying classloader behavior. It's also safer, because if, for some reason LTW is not working, you'll find it out - quite obviously - only during runtime, while that's not an issue if you incorporate weaving into your build. All in all, it's a safer, more stable alternative to LTW.

Comment: As of why the spring documentation doesn't talk about classloading issues I don't want to speculate. But I also see it as an omission, because I see the recurring questions on SO regarding `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving`.